# No Subversion Icons nor Team actions in Eclipse, have tried both Subclipse and Subversive

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse, subversive

I don't see any of the Subversion icons in Eclipse for a project that was clearly checked out from SVN (via the command line)  I'm not sure when this stopped working.

I've tried both Subclipse and Subversive plugins, they both seem content.  I've also reviewed the SVNKit vs. JavaHL stuff.

Symtoms:

- No SVN icons
- Right click on file, Team and Compare To don't have any SVN options
- In Preferences / Team I now have two SVN trees, one for Subclipse, one for Subversive

Configuration:

- Mac OS X Snow Leopard
- Eclipse 3.6 Helios
- Java / javac version 1.6.0_26 64-bit
- svn version 1.6.15
- DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/subversion/lib:/usr/lib: (have also tried SVN Kit)

I'm at a loss, it's an odd problem to Google.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to share your project first, using Team - Share project. During the wizard, it will detect .svn directories and ask if you want to keep them. Once shared, you'll see the SVN icons and additional menu items in the Team menu.

Comment: Wow, great idea, thanks.  I'm not at that machine right now, but I'll try over the weekend and report back.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similiar issue. My SVN repo version was 1.6.12 and was using svn connector SVNKit 1.3.x which is compatible with SVN1.6. I got all the  team > ..options after doing team > share project